# Как в Android изменить isChecked в динамически создаваемых Switch?

Tags: java, android

Нужно программно менять свойство `isChecked` в динамически созданных элементах `Switch`. Код фрагмента в котором создаются переключатели такой:

```
package com.cyberpole.cleverhome;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LightingsFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView textMsg;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Динамическое создание элементов фрагмента
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(context);
        int wrapContent = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int matchParent = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wrapContent, matchParent);

        textMsg = new TextView(context);
        textMsg.setId(layout.getId()+500);
        textMsg.setTextSize(20);
        textMsg.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        layout.addView(textMsg, layoutParams);
        int previousTextViewId = textMsg.getId();

        for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.maxRoomCount; i++){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsOfText = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wrapContent, wrapContent);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsOfSwitch = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wrapContent, wrapContent);
            // Добавляем текстовое поле слева
            layoutParamsOfText.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            layoutParamsOfText.topMargin = 60 + i*50;

            TextView roomName = new TextView(context);
            roomName.setId(1002 + i);
            previousTextViewId = roomName.getId();
            roomName.setGravity(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            roomName.setText(MainActivity.configRooms[i]);

            roomName.setTextSize(20);
            roomName.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsOfText);
            layout.addView(roomName);

            // Добавляем переключатель Switch
            int alignParentRight = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT;

            layoutParamsOfSwitch.addRule(alignParentRight);
            layoutParamsOfSwitch.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, previousTextViewId);
            layoutParamsOfSwitch.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, previousTextViewId);

            Switch switch1 = new Switch(context);
            switch1.setId(2002 + MainActivity.configOutputs[0][i]);
            switch1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            switch1.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsOfSwitch);

            layout.addView(switch1);
        }

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String msg = bundle.getString(MainActivity.KEY_MSG_LIGHTINGS);
            if (msg != null) {
                textMsg.setText(msg);
            }
        }
        return layout;
    }

    // Вывод текста в заголовок фрагмента
    public void setMsg(String msg){
        textMsg.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

В зависимости от меняющегося по таймеру значения некоторой переменной нужно менять состояния переключателей. При создании свичей задаю им id программно, поэтому получается id нужных элементов известны. Но как это можно после вывода элементов на экран программно менять свойство `isChecked` мне не приходит в голову. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: вопервых, так делать нельзя:`switch1.setId(2002 + MainActivity.configOutputs[0][i]);`. Возможно, в проекте уже будет такой id. Как правильно генерировать динамически ID посмотрите тут http://stackoverflow.com/a/15442898/1568530. Во вторых, вы можете сохранять свои `Switch` в переменные, и не находить их в последствии по ID, а напрямую работать с переменной.

Comment: сохранять Switch в массивы? Ведь их будет несколько, а как иначе я объявлю переменную в которую запишу потом несколько значений?

Comment: Просто уточнил. Спасибо